# Downloading big Git repos on Windows without getting "out of memory"

Tags: windows, git

When I try downloading or cloning a large Git repo I keep getting an "out of memory" error like so:

```
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory[K
remote: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 230789474 bytes)[K
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

I am using the Git GUI provided with the Git client from the Git website. The Cygwin version has the same problem.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think, it's not Windows-Git problem, but malformed repo, because</strike>

> aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side

Yes, it's common problem for 32bit Windows **and** big files: (closed) [ticket for msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=292) and [Git on Windows, “Out of memory - malloc failed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292903/git-on-windows-out-of-memory-malloc-failed) topic here.

Solution - x64, smaller files or [fine-tune git config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808378)

Comment: no, the git client on mac osx (which is how i uploaded the file to begin with) can pull it just fine

Comment: @chacham15 - oops, sorry, I'm not a sensitive to predict this. Is your repo public (or can be reached in some way) - I think to try create own clone (without any Windows-Git)

Comment: no, its a private repo but pulling on osx works just fine

Comment: Ok, it seems as well-known problem. URLs added to answer